# How to map xml to Object for consuming by RestTemplate

Tags: xml, spring, rest

I am trying to consume xml from a webservice using RestTemplate with Spring Boot ...when I call the service from the browser, the response is:

```
<ns0:IsMember>
    <inputGroupName>someGroup</inputGroupName>
    <inputUserName>someUserName</inputUserName>
    <member>true</member>
</ns0:IsMember>
```

I am getting the error:

> Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class gov.sandia.ode.domain.MetagroupInfo] and content type [application/xml].

Which I believe is because my JavaObject does not map properly to the return value...here is my java objects

```
public class MetagroupInfo {
    String inputGroupName;
    String inputUserName;
    Boolean member;
    //getters and setters
}
```

My RestTemplate call looks like:

```
MetagroupInfo response  = restTemplate.getForObject(metagroupUrl, MetagroupInfo.class);
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  I have included spring-boot-starter-web in my pom.xml  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For converting java object to/from xml by default [Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html) is pre-enabled in Spring. ( which is implementation of  [HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html). )

Here in your problem Spring not able to decide which suitable converter to use for entity MetagroupInfo for content type application/xml. **Annotate your entity with either @XMLType or @XMLRootElement**  your problem will resolve.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response...unfortunately, that did not work..I did add `@XmlSchema(namespace = "",
     elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)`  to the package-info.java fileand it now returns, but all the fields are null...

Comment: Has your original exception gone ? And why you have using package-info.java file to write code in it ? As per the coding standards it should be home for package level documentation and package level annotations. Have you marked MetagroupInfo entity with mentioned annotations ? Forgive me for multiple questions :)